# Как добавить магазин в woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

так получилось, что я удалил страницу магазина в woocommerce с целью поменять страницу магазина, на свою страницу магазина, уже сверстанную. Удалил дефолтную страницу и теперь не понимаю, как сделать другую страницу магазином. Я уже даже переустанавливал плагин, но эта страничка не возвращалась. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы моя уже сверстанная страница стала магазином в woocommerce, или же как просто вернуть дефолтную страницу магазина?))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В админке есть инструмент для создания страниц по умолчанию

/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-status&tab=tools

Admin - Woocommerce - Статус - Инструменты

Найти пункт "Создать страницы WooCommerce по умолчанию"